# Run GWT in Compiled Code

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

One of the hurdles in developing GWT apps with GAE is that its very hard to test compiled code.

Usually in a JBoss and Tomcat environment, we just compile the GWT app then upload it locally, with GAE, DevMode is the only way to test GWT app, and a compiled code would mean that it must be uploaded to the GAE cloud for testing.

Here is the question:

- In what way we can debug a compiled code for a project using GAE SDK
- If SuperDevMode is the answer, I have tried it and it does not work well with other third-party framework built on top of GWT, like JBoss Errai
- Other than SuperDevMode is there another solution?

Comment: Are you aware of http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup Yes in fact I do, however the Beta6 right now still cannot run my web app, deployment issue, where I can properly deploy it to GAE (well at least my web apps loads, only RPC fails a bit)

Comment: OK, fair enough. I'm not current on the status of CapeDwarf, but figured it might help you run locally at least.